# Modifying SharePoint search hover panel page preview

Tags: search, content-search-web-part, search-results-webpart

I would like to modify the SharePoint search results(default) hover panel to show only the body of the page, instead of the whole page with the master page and quick links on the preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using SharePoint 2013/2016. Since the default page viewer is just an IFrame, you would have to write your own that extracts the divs that you are interested in. To me, it sounds like a painful process since you will be depending on your page authors to follow standards.

Comment: Thank you Matthew, was afraid of that. I thought maybe there might be a different way